# Shipping Address is not getting transferred

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, expressionengine, expresso-store

I am facing an issue with the Paypal integration to my site which has been built using ExpressionEngine. I am using Paypal Express and Paypal Pro options.

Some orders are working fine, while some orders are facing issues related to Seller Protection.

It's showing the following information.

> Seller Protection : Not Eligible.
>
> We have no shipping address on file.
>
> Payment Type : Website Payment Pro API Solution
>
> Surcharge : Not Applicable
>
> card Type : Visa.

Also, how will I be able to test and confirm the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seller Protection is offered as a courtesy to sellers for PayPal transactions. These are non-pro, transactions that PayPal Processed through the PayPal Network. There are a few guidelines in play to ensure that you receive Seller Protection. 
Below is a link to the full details for PayPal's Seller Protection Program
[PayPal Seller Protection](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/security/seller-protection#paypal_protects_you)

Since all tangible items need to be shipped and proof of delivery (tracking number) needs to be provided to PayPal in order to receive seller protection, it is important for the shipping address to be provided to PayPal. All Express Checkout transactions for tangible goods should be passing this information to PayPal.

All PayPal Payments Pro transactions are not eligible for Seller Protection. All digital goods or non-tangible items (services rendered) are not eligible for Seller Protection.
 
The transactions that are stating they are not eligible for Seller Protection are most likely PayPal Payments Pro transactions.

Comment: Just in case you need it here, is the link to more information on Address Verification with Express Checkout[AVS API Calls PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP)